# How to draw square in pdf if any character not available in the font file using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, unicode, datatable, pdfbox

I am working to create pdf using **pdfbox 2.0** with the content available in **datatable.**
While creating pdf some of the characters are not available in the font file.

Below exception thrown if any character not available in the font.

**Note** : **AAAA** indicate unicode character and **BBBB** is the font file in the exception block.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for AAAA in font BBBB
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.encode(PDCIDFontType2.java:411)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.encode(PDType0Font.java:351)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:286)
    at com.font.test.FontTest.testFont(FontTest.java:140)
    at com.font.test.FontTest.main(FontTest.java:103)`

So, I planned to **draw or replace with square** in pdf if any character not available in the given font file.

Please help me to draw square in pdf if any character not available in the font file.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr  Do you have any idea on this qustion?

Comment: Not directly. See the EmbeddedMultipleFonts.java example in the source code download.

Comment: Yes, I can able to find all the characters not available in the font file.

My plan is to draw square instead of those characters in the pdf.

Comment: Then either use a font that has a square (probably Symbol / Zapf Dingbats, you'd have to look that up) or draw the square with PDF vector graphics. The current PDFBox behavior is on purpose. You'll also need `PDFont.getStringWidth()`.

Comment: Is the any sample blog/code available to draw a square instead of the specific character?

Comment: No. But see the ShowColorBoxes.java example on how to draw a square.